# Is there a way to get nested dictionary’s in pyparsing result?

Tags: python, pyparsing

I have the code here:

```py
#parser.py
import pyparsing as pp

class parser:
    def __init__(self):
        self.integer = pp.Word(pp.nums).set_results_name('int')
        self.string1 = pp.QuotedString(quoteChar='"')
        self.string2 = pp.QuotedString(quoteChar="'")
        self.string = pp.Or([self.string1, self.string2]).set_results_name('str')
        self.object = pp.Or([self.string, self.integer])
        self.tuple = '(' + pp.delimited_list(self.object, delim=',') + ')'
        self.tuple = self.tuple.set_results_name('tuple')
        self.object = pp.Or([self.string, self.integer, self.tuple])

        self.varname = pp.Word(pp.alphas + "_").set_results_name('varname')
        self.let_ = pp.Keyword('let')
        self.const_ = pp.Keyword('const')
        self.var_ = pp.Keyword('var')
        self.set_ = pp.one_of(": =")
        self.variable = pp.Or([pp.Or([self.let_, self.const_, self.var_]) + self.varname + self.set_ + self.object,
                               self.varname + self.set_ + self.object])

    def parseVar(self, string):
        return self.variable.parse_string(string)
#main.py

from parser import parser
parse = parser()
print(parse.parseVar('hi = ("hi", 2)').as_dict())
```

And I get:

```
{"varname":"hi', 'str': 'hi',int:"2', "tuple': ['(", 'hi', '2', ')']}
```

(sorry for the “ and ‘ swapping - *[EDIT]fixed these for you*)
But what I want to get is this:

```json
{"varname": "hi", "tuple": {"str":"hi", "int":"2"}}
```

Is there anyway I could get this result?

Comment: The quotes at the bottom aren't quotes usually used by Python. Is that how they're supposed to look in the expected output?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark No, I just have no way to turn fancy quotes off on my device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are really very very close with this. The only thing you need to do is to suppress the opening and closing parentheses from your parsed results.

This is pretty common with punctuation in parsing. The punctuation characters are super important during the parsing process, but post-parsing, they just get in the way. For your parser, I defined `tuple` as this:

```py
        LPAR = pp.Suppress("(")
        RPAR = pp.Suppress(")")
        self.tuple = pp.Group(LPAR + pp.delimited_list(self.object, delim=',') + RPAR)
```

after which I get the output that you said that you wanted.

I'm also curious, as to why you use the `Or([expr1, expr2, expr3])` style, as opposed to `expr1 | expr2 | expr3` or `expr1 ^ expr2 ^ expr3` if you truly need the more expensive match-longest behavior of pyparsing's Or. To work on your code, the first thing I did to make it easier for me to follow was to convert all those overt constructions to ones using pyparsing's overloaded operators:

```py
    def __init__(self):
        self.integer = pp.Word(pp.nums).set_results_name('int')
        self.string1 = pp.QuotedString(quoteChar='"')
        self.string2 = pp.QuotedString(quoteChar="'")
        self.string = (self.string1 | self.string2).set_results_name('str')
        self.object = self.string | self.integer
        LPAR = pp.Suppress("(")
        RPAR = pp.Suppress(")")
        self.tuple = pp.Group(LPAR + pp.delimited_list(self.object, delim=',') + RPAR)
        self.tuple = self.tuple.set_results_name('tuple')
        self.object = self.string | self.integer | self.tuple

        self.varname = pp.Word(pp.alphas + "_").set_results_name('varname')
        self.let_ = pp.Keyword('let')
        self.const_ = pp.Keyword('const')
        self.var_ = pp.Keyword('var')
        self.set_ = pp.one_of(": =")
        self.variable = pp.Optional(self.let_ | self.const_ | self.var_) + self.varname + self.set_ + self.object
```

And in truth, the only one of these that really needs to be attached to `self` is `self.variable`. All the rest can be written just a local variables (though you will probably want to change those like `object` and `tuple` which clash with Python builtins).

```py
    def __init__(self):
        integer = pp.Word(pp.nums).set_results_name('int')
        string1 = pp.QuotedString(quoteChar='"')
        string2 = pp.QuotedString(quoteChar="'")
        string = (string1 | string2).set_results_name('str')
        object = string | integer
        LPAR = pp.Suppress("(")
        RPAR = pp.Suppress(")")
        tuple = pp.Group(LPAR + pp.delimited_list(object, delim=',') + RPAR)
        tuple = tuple.set_results_name('tuple')
        object = string | integer | tuple

        varname = pp.Word(pp.alphas + "_").set_results_name('varname')
        let_ = pp.Keyword('let')
        const_ = pp.Keyword('const')
        var_ = pp.Keyword('var')
        set_ = pp.one_of(": =")
        self.variable = pp.Optional(let_ | const_ | var_) + varname + set_ + object
```